# Where to adjust slider speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been through all the javascript, modernizr, and all the other files I can think of that might be controlling the speed of the main slider at the top of this webpage.  The div is as follows:

```
<div class="image-block" id="AfWBAclyVl">
<img data-bottom-top="top: 0%;" data-top-bottom="top: -40%;" data-anchor-target="#AfWBAclyVl" data-src="images/slider/animation_1.jpg" />
<img data-bottom-top="top: 0%;" data-top-bottom="top: -40%;" data-anchor-target="#AfWBAclyVl" data-src="images/slider/animation_2.jpg" />
</div>
```

But the only javascript I can find that seems to affect slider speed is:

```
$.fn.owlCarousel.options = { slideSpeed : 200,};
```

And I can tell its not the control I'm looking for.
the website is http://sabiopleasanton.com - any thoughts at all are more than appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having trouble finding it because of how the code was obfuscated and minified. It's not being controlled via CSS. It's done in the [core.min.js](http://sabiopleasanton.com/js/core.min.js) file.

Specifically this block:

```
var m = 15e3,
    n = 4e3,
    o = !0;
a(".image-block").each(function() {
    function b() {
        var b = d[e],
            g = b.attr("data-src");
        a.imgpreload(g, {
            all: function() {
                b.attr("src", g), Modernizr.csstransitions ? (a("img", c).removeClass("active"), b.addClass("active")) : (a("img", c).velocity({
                    opacity: 0
                }, {
                    ease: i,
                    duration: n
                }), b.velocity({
                    opacity: [1, 0]
                }, {
                    ease: i,
                    duration: n
                })), o = !1
            }
        }), e++, e >= f && (e = 0)
    }
    var c = this,
        d = new Array;
    a("img", this).each(function() {
        d.push(a(this))
    });
    var e = 0,
        f = d.length;
    setInterval(b, m), b()
});
```

Here you have a variable in scientific notation `var m = 15e3` which is referenced in the `setInterval`, alter that and you should be able to change it.

Comment: I would have never, ever figured that out.  Thank you Rashad